# Advice on indexing a search table, should I or shouldn't I?

Tags: mysql

I'm making a search page on my website and I have 3 different areas that need to be searchable.

Should I make an index table for each using MyISAM engine. Or should I just put the extra data inside of the previous tables using InnoDB?

- MyISAM (separated index table)

  - benefits

    - faster loading/search
  - cons

    - need to use CRON jobs to update it daily, same data in 2 places
- InnoDB (all data in same table)

  - benefits

    - data all in one place, easier to maintain, instant updating
  - cons

    - possibly slower loading times

Does anybody have any advice on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use only InnoDB.  Period, Full Stop.

MyISAM is going away.  MyISAM is rarely faster than InnoDB.

With 5.6, you get `FULLTEXT` indexing in InnoDB.  With 5.7, you get `SPATIAL` indexing.  So, upgrade if you need to.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the information.